# Show that the vector $(\vec{x} - proj_V(\vec{x}))$ is perpendicular to $proj_V(\vec{x})$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

V is an m-dimensional subspace spanned by an orthonormal base $(u_1,u_2, \dots, u_m)$.
And the orthogonal projection is defined as
$proj_V(\vec{x}) = (\vec{x} \cdot \vec{u_1})\vec{u_1} + \dots + (\vec{x} \cdot \vec{u_m})\vec{u_m}$.

I guess it has something to do with their dot product being equal to zero, but I don't get anywhere when I do the operations. 
Thank you

Comment: What is your definition of $ proj_V(\vec{x})$ ?

Comment: I assume that $V$ is finite-dimensional?

Comment: Yes, V would be an m-dimensional subspace and has a basis consisting on orthonormal vector u1, u2.....

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, I assume that *the ambient space* (the space that $\vec x$ comes from) is finite-dimensional?

Comment: Yes, I guess the vector has the same dimension as the vector space

Comment: I have updated the question just in case it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Theorem:** Let $U$ be a finite-dimensional $\Bbb R$-inner product space.  Let $V$ be a subspace of $U$.  Then $$U=V\oplus V^\perp$$

**Exercise:** Prove this theorem.

**Corollary:** Let $U$ be a finite-dimensional $\Bbb R$-inner product space.  Let $V$ be a subspace of $U$.  Then for any $\mathbf x\in U$, $\mathbf x$ decomposes uniquely as $$\mathbf x = \operatorname{proj}_V\mathbf x + \operatorname{proj}_{V^\perp}\mathbf x$$

**Exercise:** Prove this corollary (not so difficult).

---

The above corollary implies that for any $\mathbf x\in U$, we have

$$\begin{align}(\mathbf x-\operatorname{proj}_V\mathbf x)\cdot \operatorname{proj}_V\mathbf x &= \left[(\operatorname{proj}_V\mathbf x + \operatorname{proj}_{V^\perp}\mathbf x) - \operatorname{proj}_{V}\mathbf x\right]\cdot \operatorname{proj}_{V}\mathbf x \\
&= \operatorname{proj}_{V^\perp}\mathbf x\cdot \operatorname{proj}_{V}\mathbf x \\
&=0\end{align}$$

Hence, by definition of orthogonality, $(\mathbf x-\operatorname{proj}_V\mathbf x)\perp \operatorname{proj}_V\mathbf x$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think this is going to help a lot

Answer (score 0):

For a particular case, [if the definition of $proj_{V}$ is right], think in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$:

- $v=(1,1), $
- $V = \{u\in \mathbb{R}^{2} : u=(u_{1},0)\},$
- $proj_{V}(v) = (1,0),$
- $v-proj_{V} = (0,1),$

So

<$v-proj_{V}(v), proj_{V}(v)$> = <$(0,1),(1,0)$> = $0.$

So they are orthogonal.

This can be helpful!